# Different orientation in a Multiple page PrintDocument (How to)

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have a `PrintDocument` that has several pages.
One page in that document must be in a **Landscape** orientations instead of Portrail.

As the PrintPage event is triggered for each page on the document... at the very begining of that event handler I set the `PrintPageEventArgs.PageSettings.Landscape` to true.

That doesn't works on THAT page... but I can see that Landscape is set to true and taked into account in the NEXT page.

I assume that somehow... after the event is triggered for a certain page you are not able to change the page orientation. That is more of less logic if you think it... but **HOW COULD I SET THAT FLAG before EVENT fires in a multiple page PrintDocument?**

Note: I don't know in advance if the "next" page will going to actually need a Landscape orientation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm no expert at printing in .NET; however using Reflector; it looks like you might want to handle the [QueryPageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.querypagesettings.aspx) event on PrintDocument. It looks like PrintController's private PrintLoop() method, will invoke events in this order for each page:

1. QueryPageSettings
2. StartPage
3. PrintPage
4. EndPage

Hope this helps.