# Multiple page orientation in SSRS 2008

Tags: orientation, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm preparing a series of reports in ssrs 2008.  In order to comply with the requirements the first page of the report has to be in portrait orientation, while the rest of the document must use landscape orientation.  I know there is no way to do this OOTB ( or perhaps you can prove me wrong :P ).  I was wondering if there was a way to implement a custom renderer that could play with Page Orientation based on page breaks, or any other solution you knew of.  I was reading through the questions and found this one  [Different orientation in a Multiple page PrintDocument (How to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621095/different-orientation-in-a-multiple-page-printdocument-how-to) Dunno if it could help me out with my reports.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a workaround could be to create the report in landscape and for the header page, use vertical text.

Comment: Marking as the answer. That is actually a creative idea I might use next time.