# Combination of Portrait and Landscape in one report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am using **SQL Server Reporting Services 2008**. I have a report wherein combination of **Portrait** and **Landscape** are in one report. The **Landscape** will start at the end of the **Portrait**. I need to do this because the last page has a table containing a 24 months data that is not fit in a **Portrait** Orientation.

I already tried the suggestion from other people that I must use a Main report which contains the Sub-report of the **Landscape** page and unfortunately the Sub-report renders the size of the Main report which is **Portrait**. I read that this is not possible with SSRS2008.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve on my report:

In here, I set the main report to Landscape but I need to display this in a Portrait Orientation.

[image]

Then for this last page this will be in Landscape.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple page orientation in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424775/multiple-page-orientation-in-ssrs-2008)

Comment: Hi @Viking, I think we have a different problem. mine is that on the last page, I need to Landscape the orientation because it contains a table that has a data for up to 24 months before it's only 12 months and it's looking good in a Portrait Orientation. Thanks.

Comment: You know its not do able in ssrs. I think that's the only solution. Or you can do anything in Crystal Reports